# how does grafana work by ploting graphs at regular intervals

Tags: grafana

i'm new to Grafana i want information regarding the back end operation of Grafana,how it works using java script?and how the graph will plot continuously at regular time_interval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Grafana docs](http://docs.grafana.org/plugins/developing/datasources/#datasource) has some of information you are looking for.

**Reg the internal working.**

Taking example of graph panel.

A service called timeSrv broadcasts a [refresh event](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/2b74b1c4d615ca19f7f789ea245b809d4261fb6d/public/app/features/dashboard/time_srv.ts#L138) depending on the timer set on the dashboard.

This request is caught at several places in grafana. The one we are interested in is [MetricsPanelCtrl](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/552a61b6aed65e743264af99397438e9587b72c1/public/app/features/panel/metrics_panel_ctrl.ts#L52) which is a parent of the graph panel.

From there it [issues a call to the data-source query method](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/552a61b6aed65e743264af99397438e9587b72c1/public/app/features/panel/metrics_panel_ctrl.ts#L105), which will fetch the data.

Once the data has been recieved, it emits a 'data-received' event, with is caught and handled by the [graph panel controller](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/master/public/app/plugins/panel/graph/module.ts#L129) to render the graph.